# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un menú desplegable desde un enlace?

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podrian ayudarme?.solo necesito el código(JQuery,no el CSS) que al presionar el enlace se dispare el menu. En pocas palabras un menu desplegable desde un

```
<a href="">
```

Comment: Revisa bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

Comment: Si,pero me gustaría el código JQuery.Para luego yo poder hacer modificaciones.

Comment: Aquí está un [ejemplo](https://dev7studios.com/dropit/#) haciendo uso de Dropit.

Comment: Mira, aca hay algo similar a lo que deseas intenta acomodarlo a tus necesidades, tal vez pueda servirte [bootsnipp](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/flat-user-profile-ui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUCION**

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #34495e;
    color: white;
    padding: 6px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
 height:40px;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fdfdff;
    min-width: 180px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px 0px #6a6e6f;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #008c69}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
 <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"  href="#" ><img></img>Menu</button>
   <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="#">Perfil</a>
     <a href="#">Configuracion</a>
     <a href="#">Cerrar sesion</a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Esto puede ser un menú sencillo con `JQuery` a como lo solicitas:

```js
function showMenu(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#menu").slideToggle();
}
```

```css
#menu{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#" onclick="showMenu(event)">hola</a>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li>elem1</li>
    <li>elem2</li>
    <li>elem3</li>
    <li>elem4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

**Edición**

Para que se oculte al seleccionar cualquier lado de la página habría que usar el `onblur` ya que este detectaría la perdida del "foco" del elemento.

En este caso crearía otra función para el `onblur` el cual esta haría que el menú se oculte con el método `slideUp` de `JQuery`.

```js
function showMenu(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#menu").slideToggle();
}
function hideMenu(){
  $("#menu").slideUp();
}
```

```css
#menu{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#" onclick="showMenu(event)" onblur="hideMenu()">hola</a>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li>elem1</li>
    <li>elem2</li>
    <li>elem3</li>
    <li>elem4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> En caso que quieras que al dar clic en el elemento unicamente se muestre y no se oculte al volver a dar clic cambia `slideToggle` por `slideDown`

Referencias de los `slides`

<kbd>[`slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)</kbd>,<kbd>[`slideUp`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)</kbd> y <kbd>[`slideDown`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)</kbd>

Comment: Me gusto tu respuesta, muchísimas gracias!!.Una cosita mas....Veo que hay que darle de nuevo al mismo lugar para esconderlo(el menu),acaso también no se pondría que al hacer clic en cualquier lado este se cierre??

Comment: Thank you de nuevo.Si supieras que yo estaba intentando con ""OnBlur""pero le ponía algo de mas jeje y no funcionaba,pero gracias,ahora voy al mambo.aprender y a programar.

Answer (score 3):

Revisa bootstrap, para iniciar un drowdown solo es necesaria una linea de jquery.

```css
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Menu</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
        <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" id="menu1" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda,pero el problema es que no lo quiero con Boostrap.

Comment: Entonces que necesitas?

Comment: Amigo Boostrap está aquí para facilitarte las cosas.